# Compilation, dependencies, and executable size with GHC in Linux

Tags: linux, haskell, compilation, dependencies, ghc

***Question 1***

For the reasons of improving compilation times in haskell (any module that is included is compiled, irrespective of whether the underlying functionality is used or not), is there any tool to warn a haskell programmer that unneccesary modules are being included? For example suppose that we have the following setup :

***NecessaryModule1.hs***

```
module NecessaryModule1 where

addNumber1 :: Int -> Int -> Int
addNumber1 a b = a + b
```

***NecessaryModule2.hs***

```
module NecessaryModule2 where

addNumber2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
addNumber2 a b = a + b
```

***Test.hs***

```
module Test where

import NecessaryModule1
import NecessaryModule2
```

***Main.hs***

```
module Main where
import Test

myadd :: Int->Int->Int
myadd a b = a + b

main::IO()
main = print(myadd 5 6)
```

Then such a tool would warn you that there are unnecessary modules in :

- Main.hs : because functionality of Test is not used
- Test.hs : because functionality of NecessaryModule1 and NecessaryModule2 is not used

---

---

***Question 2***

If I compile the code above via :

```
ghc -o testProg Main.hs
```

then I get an executable size of 833504 bytes. However if I change **Main.hs** to :

***Main.hs***

```
module Main where
--import Test

myadd :: Int->Int->Int
myadd a b = a + b

main::IO()
main = print(myadd 5 6)
```

then the executable size reduces to 833057. Given that the functionality of the Test module is not being used in **Main.hs**, why is there a difference in the executable size?

Comment: One question per post. Also executable size doesn't really matter.

Comment: The normal compilation process probably doesn't eliminate any unused code. Try again again with optimizations (ghc -O2) to see if that changes things.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It matters in some areas (think embedded, or an installer's [Boostrapper](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) (see feature list->size)). It also matters when it get excessive (e.g. a three-line script with a 15 MB executable due to embedding a whole Python implementation) not for the individual case but for when you have a hundred programs thinking all your RAM is belong to them.

Comment: Executable size *definitely* doesn't matter when the differences are both <500 bytes and <0.1%.

Comment: The reason why I was asking about the small differences in executable size was not because I was concerned in any way with it, but simply because I wanted to understand why there was a difference. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1** Haskell cannot warn you about unused modules, because they might be imported by another package in the future. When you import modules, only those that you import will be linked, however, so if you create an executable with a module that is never imported, that module won't be included in the executable unless you explicitly tell `cabal` to link it.

When you actually import a module, GHC can warn you that you don't use that module if you pass the `-fwarn-unused-imports` flag while compiling. You should also consider using `-Wall`, which will enable this warning and many other useful warnings. Using `-Werror` will make GHC refuse to compile modules with warnings such as unused imports or dead code.

You can also pass the flag `-split-objs` to GHC, which will make GHC create one object file per function (more or less) instead of one object file per module, making it possible to reduce executable size considerably.

**Q2** The Template Haskell language extension can browse the local scope of a module as part of some of its functionality. It is therefore necessary for GHC to include explicitly imported code when compiling a module, because there might be some TH functionality that depends on it. Enabling some levels of optimization (like `-O2`) should probably strip that unused code again, but it's not guaranteed.

You might consider compiling with the `-shared` compilation flag, which will compile using shared libraries and drastically reduce overall binary size, with the disadvantage that you'll have to copy library files along if you want to use a compiled binary on a different computer.

Comment: Wow thanks. That was really useful. I compiled via "ghc -Wall -Werror -o testProg Main.hs" and it failed because of unused modules, just as you said. Cheers.

Comment: @dflemstr I just want to say that I'm continually amazed at the quality of your answers.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, thanks! I guess that I find it to be incredibly fun, and a great learning experience, since I've never actually academically studied Haskell, and knew next to nothing about the language less than a year ago, so I do a lot of research for each answered question sometimes.